# Поймать Java Exception

Tags: java, oracle, исключения

Разработанное ПО, грузится на tomcat. Cторона клиента построена во flex. Есть 2 базы, с которыми работает ПО. При накате пакетов на тестовую бд возникает ошибка, на промышленной бд такой ошибки не возникает.
Ошибка:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20000: ,BS - 1 Ошибка при занесении файла во временные таблицы . ORA-06512: at "BS.BS_FLEX_LOADDOCS", line 380
>   ,LD -  Ошибка загрузки во временные таблицы: ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.io.IOException. ORA-06512: at "LD.PG_BLOBEXP", line 9
>   ORA-06512: at "LD.PG_BLOBEXP", line 113
>   ORA-06512: at "BS.BS_FLEX_LOADDOCS", line 395
>   ORA-06512: at line 14
>   ' faultDetail:'null' metasys.ascr.integration.AscrRemoteExeption : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [72000]; error code [20000]; ORA-20000: ,BS - 1 Ошибка при занесении файла во временные таблицы . ORA-06512: at "BS.BS_FLEX_LOADDOCS", line 380
>   ,LD -  Ошибка загрузки во временные таблицы: ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.io.IOException. ORA-06512: at "LD.PG_BLOBEXP", line 9
>   ORA-06512: at "LD.PG_BLOBEXP", line 113
>   ORA-06512: at "BS.BS_FLEX_LOADDOCS", line 395
>   ORA-06512: at line 14
>   ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20000: ,BS - 1 Ошибка при занесении файла во временные таблицы . ORA-06512: at "BS.BS_FLEX_LOADDOCS", line 380
>   ,LD -  Ошибка загрузки во временные таблицы: ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.io.IOException. ORA-06512: at "LD.PG_BLOBEXP", line 9
>   ORA-06512: at "LD.PG_BLOBEXP", line 113
>   ORA-06512: at "BS.BS_FLEX_LOADDOCS", line 395
>   ORA-06512: at line 14
>    Server.Processing null

Есть предположение, что админы намудрили с правами. Как можно достать более подробную информацию о ошибке?

Comment: Какие именно операции и с какими аргументами вызываются в тех местах, где произошла ошибка? Можете показать код?

Comment: Если у приложения никаких дополнительных логов нет - то никак, наверное. У вас есть возможность посмотреть в БД код пакетов `BS` и `LD`? Я бы с этого начал, например, берем `ORA-06512: at "LD.PG_BLOBEXP", line 113` и смотрим строку 113, и т. д. Flex я не знаю, если что.

Comment: @Dmitry перепроверил код, в тех местах где указывает `ORA-06512:`, никаких к нему претензий нет. Так что возвращаюсь к своему первому вопросу. Как можно вывести более подробную информацию?
А Flex, в моем понимании просто служит для Web оформления. Главная проблема взаимодействия Oracle и Java. Я писал что на промышленной базе все работает а на тестовой - вот такая беда. Остается грешить на недостаток привилегий и места загрузки, ибо это другой сервак

Comment: @OlegChiruhin та думаю в коде ошибки нет, только в сервере и в привилегиях юзера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из ваших слов о том, что никаких претензий к коду нет и возможно проблема с правами, сделал такой пример. Создаем пользователей `user1` и `user2`, у первого пользователя создаем таблицу `t`, даем на нее права второму пользователю:

```
create table t (id number);
grant select on t to user2;
```

Далее у пользователя `user2` создаем две процедуры:

```
create or replace procedure proc1 is
a number;
begin
  select id
    into a
    from user1.t
    where id = 1;
end;
/

create or replace procedure proc2 is
begin
  proc1;
end;
/
```

Выполняем под вторым пользователем:

```
begin
  proc2;
end;
/
```

Все ОК.
Далее отзываем права на таблицу:

```
revoke select on t from user2;
```

Выполняем еще раз:

```
begin
  proc2;
end;
/

Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "USER2.PROC1", line 4
ORA-06512: at "USER2.PROC2", line 3
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Единственное, что смущает - у вас нет сообщений об отсутствии соответствующих объектов, доступа к которым не хватает. Но в принципе, такие сообщения и спрятать можно. Нужно проверить, к каким объектам обращаются процедуры в тех строках, где возникают ошибки, под каким пользователем вызываются процедуры, и какие у кого права доступа. Еще не лишним будет проверить, есть ли `AUTHID` у пакетов (`create package <pkg> authid current_user ...`) - от этого параметра зависит, с чьими правами пакет выполняется.
Про проверку прав: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298473/how-can-i-list-all-grants-a-user-received

Comment: Cпасибо большое, по пробую и напишу, что получилось.
Еще забыл указать, что при начале работы с ПО появляется такое сообщение:
> org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Влияет ли она как то на эту проблему?

Comment: `ORA-12514` - это приложение не может установить подключение к базе. Это точно не влияет, непонятно только, почему это сообщение показывается, ведь в итоге подключиться к базе удается.

Comment: А вот что вытянул с "инструментов разработчика", помимо  тех что указал вначале:
unknown problem occurred during a remote call : faultCode:Server.Processing faultString:'metasys.ascr.integration.AscrRemoteExeption : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [72000]; error code [20000];

Comment: Это что-то джавовское похоже, я в джаве не силен.

Comment: Спасибо, статья помогла, однако моя проблема не пропала, дело видимо не в правах